# What is required in an XSD schema to generate an @XmlElementDecl method?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I am confused as to how the `@XmlElementDecl` annotation is generated from a `WSDL` file that was generated by an `XSD` file. I have noticed that there are tags in my `XSD` file that are formatted in the following manner:

```
<xsd:element>...</xsd:element>
```

and others are formatted as such:

```
<element>...</element>
```

or they have a `type="element"` attribute. The latter two types do not generate any code that contains the `@XmlElementDecl` annotation, but the first format does.

The annotation is present in the `ObjectFactory` file.

Does this mean there is a requirement for the schema to have `xsd:element` as a prefix?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use @XmlElementDecl along with @XmlRegistry annotation in the class to generate the element. You can find this link with an example.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementDecl.html

Comment: That makes sense but if I'm starting from an XSD schema file and work my way towards the WSDL and the generated classes, how would you declare the "XmlRegistry" annotation?